# Setting the date to a date picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uidatepicker

I made a datePicker and I want to show the last date used when I use the datePicker again. I have made a save for the datePicker to the user defaults and I tried to set the date to the date I saved. Here is my code:

```
datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    datepicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    datepicker.minuteInterval = 5;
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

    [datepicker setDate:selectedDate];

    [textfield setInputView:datepicker];
```

---

This is in the Value did change

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSDate *selectedDate = [datepicker date];

    [defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"selectedDate"];
```

But I get the error

```
 Use of undeclared identifier 'selectedDate'
```

Do I need to put something in the header file?

---

### Edit

I tried putting this in the header file, but the app now crashes when I press the button to get to the view controller with the datePicker. It crashes sue to an uncaught exception.

```
 NSDate *selectedDate;
```

---

### Edit 2

I Tried this code and I am getting an error

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaul = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedDate"] != nil) {

        NSDate *selectedDate = [defaul dataForKey:@"selectedDate"];
```

and in the pickerDidChange

```
NSUserDefaults *defaul = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSDate *selectedDates = [datepicker date];

    [defaul setObject:selectedDates forKey:@"selectedDate"];
```

The error is `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDate *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSData *'`

---

### Edit 3

I thought this said dateForKey
`NSDate *selectedDate = [defaul dataForKey:@"selectedDate"];`

so i changed it to

`NSDate *selectedDate = [defaul objectForKey:@"selectedDate"];`

and now the picker works how I would want it to.

Comment: You asked this question before, and I answered it. You did not accept the answer, instead you deleted that question and reposted this one sprinkled in with code I gave you. As stated before, SO is not a place to go to have someone write your classes for you.

Comment: I think this was less about redoing it and more about trying to find a way to have users write code for you. This is not good use of SO.

Comment: You're also giving no one rep this way. People are doing work for you and you're not rewarding their work.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

You aren't use ARC and not retain `selectedDate`

You can:

.h

`@property(retain,nonatomic) NSDate selectedDate;`

.m

`@synthesize selectedDate`

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     self.selectedDate = nil;
     [super dealloc];
}
```

and

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//NSDate *selectedDate = [datepicker date];
self.selectedDate = [datepicker date];

[defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"selectedDate"];
```

Comment: Sorry, I was using arc, so this was close, but didn't work for me. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code block, you had this line

```
[datepicker setDate:selectedDate];
```

but at that time `selectedDate` hasn't been initialized (because `valueDidChange` didn't get called), that's why the compiler is complaining.

To fix it, you need to set `selectedDate` to some date *before* calling `[datepicker setDate:]`.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to initialize your instance variable selectedDate,by default it will be nil and will cause crash,check if it is nil before use it to set your DatePicker date.

Edited:**check it is nil before use it**,I already told you what to do.

Code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
selectedDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"selectedDate"]; 
if(selectedDate){
    [datepicker setDate:selectedDate];
}
```